# Java Having trouble reading the output of my code

Tags: java

```
public int[] biggerTwo(int[] a, int[] b) {
      int suma = 0;
      int sumb = 0;
      for(int x = 0; x < a.length; x ++){
          a[x] += suma;
      }
      for(int x = 0; x < b.length; x ++){
          b[x] += sumb;
      }
      if(suma >= sumb)
          return a;
      else
          return b;
}
```

This is the code I wrote to return the list with the largest sum. In CodingBat im getting it wrong on only two tests.

```
biggerTwo({1, 2}, {3, 4})    Mine returns {1,2}
biggerTwo({1, 1}, {1, 2})    Mine returns {1,1}
```

Everything else is correct, and I'm not sure why.
Also, during the else statement I noticed that initially I had else if(sumb > suma), which I changed to else knowing if !(suma >= sumb) it means sumb > suma, but it causes an error when I typed out the else if?

If anyone can see the error I'd appreciate it :D

Comment: Not sure what you mean by everything else is correct since you add 0 to each element of the arrays.

Comment: Since this problem is quite basic, I suggest you to learn how to use your IDE's debug functionality, and you can easily find the problem yourself. Also I post an answer in the answer section.

Answer (score 7):

You're confusing

```
a[x] += suma;
```

with

```
suma += a[x];
```

Answer (score 1):

**In your code, the suma and sumb will never change**
You should assign `suma += a[x]` and `sumb += b[x]`

BTW, since suma/b is the sum of an array of integer.
**I strongly suggest you use `long` to store the sum to avoid overflow**!

Answer (score 0):

You've swapped the array element and the variable you are summing in your loop body arithmetic. Also, I would try to follow the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) by extracting the sumation into a method. Something like (using a [`for-each` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html)),

```
static long sumArray(int[] arr) {
    long sum = 0;
    for (int val : arr) {
        sum += val;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

And then `biggerTwo` could be implemented in one line with a [ternary operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation) like

```
public int[] biggerTwo(int[] a, int[] b) {
    return sumArray(a) < sumArray(b) ? b : a;
}
```

Comment: Why does my code not return any value  if I write. else if (sumb > suma) return b; instead of else? I mean it's literally what !(suma >= sumb) is, but it doesn't work?